# Add Office 2013-like animations to my C# application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, office-2013

So, in Office 2013, the applications have animations such as a "smooth typing" animation, along with things such as the email list in Outlook smoothly moving emails rather than just deleting one out of the list, or having the Backstage View smoothly slide out from the side of the screen. I'd like to add some similar animations to my applications in the future.

I have some ideas in my head about how to animate these, but before I dive into a lot of custom work I was wondering if anyone knew of a framework or something that added support for this type of thing easily.

Also, I have previously done all my work in WinForms- in your opinion, would it be better for me to take this as an opportunity to start learning WPF? I've heard a few times it's more "animation friendly".

Thanks!

Comment: winforms is a dinosaur. It doesn't support animations, transparency, gradients or anything that looks good. It only supports looking like windows 95. If you want something to look and feel like it's at least from this century, you need to do it with this century's technologies.

Comment: Good point, stupid question on my part I suppose :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take this as an opportunity to learn WPF. WPF is great with animations and it uses hardware acceleration to increase performance (provided you're not running on WinXP or anything before that).

You can also look into acquiring Microsoft Blend which will help you create animations in your WPF applications.

I would also suggest [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672331195). I haven't seen a better resource than this.

Comment: It's important to mention that WPF is not only about "Eye Candy". There's A LOT more to it. It simplifies development A LOT by introducing capabilities such as `DataBinding`, `Data and Control Templating`, `Styles`, and supports the MVVM pattern which, when implemented (correctly) increases your code quality and cleanliness A LOT and reduces the amount of boilerplate to almost zero.

Comment: Will do, and thanks for the book reference and info, both of you.

Comment: Yes, you are very right. It's important to note that because of this WPF has a steep learning curve, but once you get it you'll start to love it.